# collections counter python can't access the key

Tags: python, python-collections

I am using the collections counter to count each string (they might not be unique) inside lists. The problem is that now I can't access the dictionary, and I am not sure why.

My code is:

```
from collections import Counter
result1  = Counter(list_final1) #to count strings inside list
```

If I print result1, output is for example:

```
Counter({'BAM': 44, 'CCC': 20, 'APG': 14, 'MBI': 11, 'BAV': 10})
```

To access the number 44 for exampke I would expect to use Counter['BAM']

But this above doesnt work and I get the error:

```
    print (Counter['BAM'])
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try `result1['BAM']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your `key` with the variable in which you stored the value of `Counter`, in your case `result1`. Sample:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> my_dict = {'BAM': 44, 'CCC': 20, 'APG': 14, 'MBI': 11, 'BAV': 10}
>>> result = Counter(my_dict)
>>> result['BAM']
44
```

**Explaination**:

You are doing `Counter['BAM']`, i.e making new `Counter` object with `'BAM'` as param, which is invalid. Instead if you do `Counter(my_dict)['BAM']`, it will also work since it is the same object in which your dict is passed, and you are accessing `'BAM'` key within it

Comment: humm,, it works! But I didnt understand.. it means that this dict created by the collections counter is not the same as any other dict? Could you elaborate please.

Comment: It is same. But you are doing `Counter['BAM']`, i.e making new `Counter` object with `'BAM'` as param, which is invalid. Instead if you do `Counter(my_dict)['BAM']`, it will also work since it is the same object in which your dict is passed, and you are accessing `'BAM'` key within it